# Accounts Created via Terraform not in state

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-organizations

I have been using Terraform to create an AWS Organisation and three additional accounts within it.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
  cloud {
    hostname     = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "MyOrg"

    workspaces {
      name = "MyWorkspace"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
}

resource "aws_organizations_organization" "organization" {
}

resource "aws_organizations_account" "users" {
  name      = "users"
  email     = "users@example.com"
  role_name = "Admin"
}

resource "aws_organizations_account" "staging" {
  name      = "staging"
  email     = "staging@example.com"
  role_name = "Admin"
}

resource "aws_organizations_account" "production" {
  name      = "production"
  email     = "production@example.com"
  role_name = "Admin"
}

provider "aws" {
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${aws_organizations_account.users.id}:role/Admin"
  }

  alias  = "users"
  region = var.aws_region
}

provider "aws" {
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${aws_organizations_account.users.id}:role/Admin"
  }

  alias  = "staging"
  region = var.aws_region
}

provider "aws" {
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${aws_organizations_account.users.id}:role/Admin"
  }

  alias  = "production"
  region = var.aws_region
}

resource "aws_iam_group" "self_managing" {
  name = "SelfManaging"

  provider = aws.users
}

resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "iam_read_only_access" {
  group      = aws_iam_group.self_managing.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/IAMReadOnlyAccess"

  provider = aws.users
}

resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "iam_self_manage_service_specific_credentials" {
  group      = aws_iam_group.self_managing.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/IAMSelfManageServiceSpecificCredentials"

  provider = aws.users
}

resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "iam_user_change_password" {
  group      = aws_iam_group.self_managing.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/IAMUserChangePassword"

  provider = aws.users
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "self_manage_vmfa" {
  name   = "SelfManageVMFA"
  policy = file("${path.module}/data/self_manage_vmfa.json")

  provider = aws.users
}

resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "self_manage_vmfa" {
  group      = aws_iam_group.self_managing.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.self_manage_vmfa.arn

  provider = aws.users
}

module "developer_role_staging" {
  source         = "./modules/developer-role"
  trusted_entity = "arn:aws:iam::${aws_organizations_account.users.id}:root"

  providers = {
    aws = aws.staging
  }
}

module "developer_role_production" {
  source         = "./modules/developer-role"
  trusted_entity = "arn:aws:iam::${aws_organizations_account.users.id}:root"

  providers = {
    aws = aws.production
  }
}

module "developer_group_staging" {
  source     = "./modules/developer-group"
  group_name = "DevelopersStaging"

  assume_role_arns = [
    module.developer_role_staging.role_arn,
  ]

  providers = {
    aws = aws.users
  }
}

module "developer_group_production" {
  source     = "./modules/developer-group"
  group_name = "DevelopersProduction"

  assume_role_arns = [
    module.developer_role_production.role_arn
  ]

  providers = {
    aws = aws.users
  }
}
```

The user I was running Terraform with did not have quite the right permissions. The Organisation and the accounts were created, but it appears that the state does not contain them. If I run `terraform apply` then it shows that it will add them. However, once accept the plan I get the following error for each account:-

`Error: Error waiting for account request (car-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) to become available: EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS`

I read the [documentation for aws_organizations_account resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/organizations_account#import) which states I can use `terraform import aws_organizations_account.my_org 111111111111` to import it into state. However, when I run that I get several:-

```sh
Error: Invalid provider configuration
│
│   on path-to\main.tf line 42:
│   42: provider "aws" {
│
│ The configuration for provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].users depends on values that cannot be determined until apply.
```

I am really stuck and would appreciate some pointers.

**UPDATE**
As requested I have added the output of `terraform plan`

```sh
Terraform v1.1.0
on linux_amd64
Configuring remote state backend...    
Initializing Terraform configuration...
aws_organizations_organization.organization: Refreshing state... [id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create
 <= read (data resources)

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_iam_group.self_managing will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group" "self_managing" {
      + arn       = (known after apply)
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + name      = "SelfManaging"
      + path      = "/"
      + unique_id = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_iam_group_policy_attachment.iam_read_only_access will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "iam_read_only_access" {
      + group      = "SelfManaging"
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/IAMReadOnlyAccess"
    }

  # aws_iam_group_policy_attachment.iam_self_manage_service_specific_credentials will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "iam_self_manage_service_specific_credentials" {
      + group      = "SelfManaging"
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/IAMSelfManageServiceSpecificCredentials"
    }

  # aws_iam_group_policy_attachment.iam_user_change_password will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "iam_user_change_password" {
      + group      = "SelfManaging"
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/IAMUserChangePassword"
    }

  # aws_iam_group_policy_attachment.self_manage_vmfa will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "self_manage_vmfa" {
      + group      = "SelfManaging"
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_iam_policy.self_manage_vmfa will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_policy" "self_manage_vmfa" {
      + arn       = (known after apply)
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + name      = "SelfManageVMFA"
      + path      = "/"
      + policy    = jsonencode(
            {
              + Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action   = [
                          + "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                          + "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                          + "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
                          + "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice",
                        ]
                      + Effect   = "Allow"
                      + Resource = [
                          + "arn:aws:iam::*:mfa/${aws:username}",
                          + "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}",
                        ]
                    },
                  + {
                      + Action    = [
                          + "iam:DeactivateMFADevice",
                        ]
                      + Condition = {
                          + Bool = {
                              + aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent = "true"
                            }
                        }
                      + Effect    = "Allow"
                      + Resource  = [
                          + "arn:aws:iam::*:mfa/${aws:username}",
                          + "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}",
                        ]
                      + Sid       = "AllowUsersToDeactivateTheirOwnVirtualMFADevice"
                    },
                  + {
                      + Action   = [
                          + "iam:ListMFADevices",
                          + "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                          + "iam:ListUsers",
                        ]
                      + Effect   = "Allow"
                      + Resource = "*"
                    },
                ]
              + Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
      + policy_id = (known after apply)
      + tags_all  = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_organizations_account.production will be created
  + resource "aws_organizations_account" "production" {
      + arn              = (known after apply)
      + email            = "production@example.com"
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + joined_method    = (known after apply)
      + joined_timestamp = (known after apply)
      + name             = "production"
      + parent_id        = (known after apply)
      + role_name        = "Admin"
      + status           = (known after apply)
      + tags_all         = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_organizations_account.staging will be created
  + resource "aws_organizations_account" "staging" {
      + arn              = (known after apply)
      + email            = "staging@example.com"
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + joined_method    = (known after apply)
      + joined_timestamp = (known after apply)
      + name             = "staging"
      + parent_id        = (known after apply)
      + role_name        = "Admin"
      + status           = (known after apply)
      + tags_all         = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_organizations_account.users will be created
  + resource "aws_organizations_account" "users" {
      + arn              = (known after apply)
      + email            = "users@example.com"
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + joined_method    = (known after apply)
      + joined_timestamp = (known after apply)
      + name             = "users"
      + parent_id        = (known after apply)
      + role_name        = "Admin"
      + status           = (known after apply)
      + tags_all         = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.developer_group_production.data.template_file.assume_role will be read during apply
  # (config refers to values not yet known)
 <= data "template_file" "assume_role"  {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + rendered = (known after apply)
      + template = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.developer_group_production.aws_iam_group.this will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group" "this" {
      + arn       = (known after apply)
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + name      = "DevelopersProduction"
      + path      = "/"
      + unique_id = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.developer_group_production.aws_iam_group_policy_attachment.assume_role will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "assume_role" {
      + group      = "DevelopersProduction"
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.developer_group_production.aws_iam_policy.assume_role will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_policy" "assume_role" {
      + arn       = (known after apply)
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + name      = "DevelopersProductionAssumeRole"
      + path      = "/"
      + policy    = (known after apply)
      + policy_id = (known after apply)
      + tags_all  = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.developer_group_staging.data.template_file.assume_role will be read during apply
  # (config refers to values not yet known)
 <= data "template_file" "assume_role"  {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + rendered = (known after apply)
      + template = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.developer_group_staging.aws_iam_group.this will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group" "this" {
      + arn       = (known after apply)
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + name      = "DevelopersStaging"
      + path      = "/"
      + unique_id = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.developer_group_staging.aws_iam_group_policy_attachment.assume_role will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "assume_role" {
      + group      = "DevelopersStaging"
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.developer_group_staging.aws_iam_policy.assume_role will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_policy" "assume_role" {
      + arn       = (known after apply)
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + name      = "DevelopersStagingAssumeRole"
      + path      = "/"
      + policy    = (known after apply)
      + policy_id = (known after apply)
      + tags_all  = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.developer_role_production.data.template_file.trust_relationship will be read during apply
  # (config refers to values not yet known)
 <= data "template_file" "trust_relationship"  {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + rendered = (known after apply)
      + template = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.developer_role_production.aws_iam_role.this will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_role" "this" {
      + arn                   = (known after apply)
      + assume_role_policy    = (known after apply)
      + create_date           = (known after apply)
      + force_detach_policies = false
      + id                    = (known after apply)
      + managed_policy_arns   = (known after apply)
      + max_session_duration  = 3600
      + name                  = "Developer"
      + name_prefix           = (known after apply)
      + path                  = "/"
      + tags_all              = (known after apply)
      + unique_id             = (known after apply)

      + inline_policy {
          + name   = (known after apply)
          + policy = (known after apply)
        }
    }

  # module.developer_role_production.aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.administrator_access will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "administrator_access" {
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"
      + role       = "Developer"
    }

  # module.developer_role_staging.data.template_file.trust_relationship will be read during apply
  # (config refers to values not yet known)
 <= data "template_file" "trust_relationship"  {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + rendered = (known after apply)
      + template = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.developer_role_staging.aws_iam_role.this will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_role" "this" {
      + arn                   = (known after apply)
      + assume_role_policy    = (known after apply)
      + create_date           = (known after apply)
      + force_detach_policies = false
      + id                    = (known after apply)
      + managed_policy_arns   = (known after apply)
      + max_session_duration  = 3600
      + name                  = "Developer"
      + name_prefix           = (known after apply)
      + path                  = "/"
      + tags_all              = (known after apply)
      + unique_id             = (known after apply)

      + inline_policy {
          + name   = (known after apply)
          + policy = (known after apply)
        }
    }

  # module.developer_role_staging.aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.administrator_access will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "administrator_access" {
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"
      + role       = "Developer"
    }
```

Comment: Please update with the plan output for one of the accounts.

Comment: @MattSchuchard - thanks for your input. I have added what you asked for.

Comment: That is attempting to create every managed resource, which implies the issue is with your state storage.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I agree. I believe that the user that Terraform was running under did not have the right permissions to query AWS to populate the state. I'm just not sure how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Check the state file in your Terraform Cloud workspace. If it does not look correct, then this could be a TF Cloud issue where the backend initialization or subsequent actions should have failed prior to appying.